# Java: Maven and Library compiling

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compilation

I'm trying to compile a project which has got Maven dependencies and normal dependencies (the ones you would add the .jar to your buildpath/lib). However, I can only choose one ;( Either, I compile with Maven, or I compile with artifacts, and that won't make the project work.

I use

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>me.expdev.testproject.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

to compile. But I also have 5 jars (which are not available as Maven) which I need included in the packaging jar output! It works fine when I run Main in my IDE.

I USE IntelliJ Community Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can package the 3rd party jars as Maven artifacts.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar
```

The `<group-id>`, `<artifact-id>` and `<version>` fields are completely up to you to fill, choose values that seem appropriate to you. The artifact will be available to Maven by these values. See other Maven artifacts already in your project for examples. For the group id, choose some prefix to make it clear that it's not a publicly published jar, to avoid confusion. For example `custom.`, as in `custom.some.package`, but it's really up to you.

For more details, see: [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Also keep in mind that other developers who want to use the project will have to do the same, and manually install the jars in their local Maven repositories. Another option is to run your own Maven repository. See this article: http://stuartsierra.com/2009/09/08/run-your-own-maven-repository
.

Comment: The group id of my maven project? and could you fill in the params as an example? I tried `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=customizer.jar -DgroupId=me.expdev -DartifactId=testproject -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
` but it said i was missing packaging, what would this be?

Comment: I added more information. For packaging, use `jar`.

Comment: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project testproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project me.expdev:testproject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: me.expdev:customizer:jar:1.0, me.expdev:jmf:jar:1.0, me.expdev:mediaplayer:j
ar:1.0, me.expdev:multiplayer:jar:1.0, me.expdev:sound:jar:1.0: Failure to find me.expdev:customizer:jar:1.0 in https://raw.github.com/kristian/system-hook/mvn-repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interva
l of system-hook-mvn-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1
`

Comment: @ExpDev not sure what you're doing there, but perhaps it's a follow-up question?

Comment: Well, I did as you said, now all downloaded dependencies are in my local resp, [repo](https://gyazo.com/367616e7f6b7f2cdfc5ecc4eae239abd), and in my project pom I have `    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>system-hook-mvn-repo</id>
            <url>https://raw.github.com/kristian/system-hook/mvn-repo/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>` but didn't specify my local, is that the issue? and how to fix?

Comment: For  `mvn install:install-file`, you don't need to define `<repositories>` at all. Remove that part.

Comment: all i did was `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sound.jar -DgroupId=me.expdev -DartifactId=sound -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=package
` not repo, but when i add the installed/local dependency to my pom.xml it says it can't find it in repo

Comment: @ExpDev packaging should be `jar`, not `package`